# Streaming private videos from Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-s3, video-streaming, wordpress

I need to display videos / images file with ACL:PRIVATE uploaded to my Amazon S3 account on my wordpress blog.

I am a newbie to PHP oops based coding. Any script help, link references, free plugins or even Logical Algorithm  will be great help :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can start by looking at the SDK for PHP: http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/ Also go through the code samples, they are very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

This issue could be solved by implementing the following steps:

1. Download latest stable version of SDK from [here](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/)
2. Extract the .zip file & place in `wamp/www` folder
3. Rename config-sample.inc.php file to **config.inc.php**
4. Add the **access key & secret key** (retrieved from Amazon S3 account) into above file, save & exit
5. create a sample file to display public / private objects from Amazon S3

The content of the file should look as follows:

```
require('sdk.class.php');
require('services/s3.class.php');

$s3 = new AmazonS3();
$bucket = "bucketname";
$temp_link = $s3->get_object_url($bucket, 'your/folder/path/img.jpg', '5 minute');

echo $temp_link;
```

In above code, the URL you receive as output is a signed URL for your private object, thus it is valid only for 5 minutes.

You may grant access for a future date and allow only authorized users to access your private content or media on Amazon S3.

Answer (score 2):

This question is a little bit old, but I'm posting it anyway. I had a simliar issue today and found out there's a simple answer.

aws doc explains it clearly and has an example as well.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/service-s3.html#amazon-s3-stream-wrapper

Basically, you need to register AWS' stream wrapper and use s3:// protocol.

Here's my code sample.

```
use Aws\Common\Aws;
use Aws\S3\Enum\CannedAcl;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$s3 = Aws::factory(array(
    'key'    => Config::get('aws.key'),
    'secret' => Config::get('aws.secret'),
    'region' => Config::get('aws.region')
))->get('s3');

$s3->registerStreamWrapper();

// now read file from s3
// from the doc.

// Open a stream in read-only mode
if ($stream = fopen('s3://bucket/key', 'r')) {
    // While the stream is still open
    while (!feof($stream)) {
        // Read 1024 bytes from the stream
        echo fread($stream, 1024);
    }
    // Be sure to close the stream resource when you're done with it
    fclose($stream);
}
```

Comment: I have shared this & it's working properly on Firefox. However, on chrome dragging/seeking of the video is not working. Any clue?

Comment: This got me up and running in seconds.  But when I click a link to move away from the streaming video, it continues playing for 30 secs.  Any ideas on how to stop it mid-stream?